# Unable to access Firebase Firestore data through $scope variables in AngularJS 1.8.2

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find the number of documents inside a collection in Firestore database and assigning that number to $scope variables in AngularJS. I know that queries in Firestore work asynchronously and I am using async/await as well. Still no luck!!! Below is the code.

Controller code:

```
myProject.controller("Dashboard", function($scope){
$scope.setCases = async function($scope){
    const query = firestore.collection('Cases1');
    const lowerLimit = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)));
    const upperLimit = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(new Date().setHours(23,59,59,0)));
    const currentTimestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());
    
    //Todays cases
    const snapshot1 = await query.where("start", ">=", lowerLimit).where("start", "<=", upperLimit).get();
    $scope.todaysCases = snapshot1.size();

    // Upcoming Cases
    const snapshot2 = await query.where("start", ">", currentTimestamp).get();
    $scope.upcomingCases = snapshot2.size();
}
```

});

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Dashboard">
<div ng-init="setCases(this)">
    <p>{{todaysCases}}</p>
    <p>{{upcomingCases}}</p>
</div>
```

Note: When I try to print the $scope variables to the console inside the function they are getting displayed in the console but not able to access them with expressions in HTML. The above HTML code is my view.

Insights on this issue would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: I would recommend against using async/await in an AngularJS project. That mechanism uses vanilla JavaScript promises, while the AngularJS change detection mechanism relies on you using its integrated promise mechanism. That's why you were required to manually trigger the change detection. That's what the `$scope.apply()` in your answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Its weird to answer my own question, lol!!! below line did the job.

```
$scope.$apply()
```